# reinstall windowing system?

Tags: apt

Somehow, I managed to uninstall something I shouldn't have.

When I rebooted, the login-screen was showing normally, but after that the desktop was black (though some icons were there, and I could start those programs), there was no launcher, and I could not open a terminal window.

On the text interface (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) I reinstalled `unity`, which give me the GUI back, but now it's a bit antiquated-looking, and handles differently (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a terminal window, but not focused). And `apt` tells me, there are many unused dependencies (see below).

Any idea, which is the package I inadvertently removed? Any other things I might need to bear in mind?

Many thanks.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas
 accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas address-book-service
 app-install-data apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data apturl-common biometryd-bin
cgmanager click-apparmor content-hub dpkg-repack dvd+rw-tools
ethtool evolution-data-server-utouch folks-common gedit-common
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
gnome-software-common gnome-terminal-data growisofs
history-service hplip-data indicator-network indicator-transfer
indicator-transfer-download-manager intel-gpu-tools
libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libbiometryd1
libboost-locale1.61.0 libboost-log1.61.0 libboost-python1.61.0
libboost-regex1.61.0 libboost-serialization1.61.0 libcapnp-0.5.3
libconnectivity-qt1 libcontent-hub0 libdbus-cpp5 libfolks-eds25
libfolks25 libgflags2v5 libgoogle-glog0v5 libgspell-1-1
libgspell-1-common libgtkspell3-3-0 libhardware2
libhistoryservice0 libhud2 libhybris libhybris-common1
libindicator-transfer0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjsoncpp1
libleveldb1v5 liblightdm-qt5-3-0 libmedia1
libmission-control-plugins0 libnet-cpp2
libonline-accounts-client1 libonline-accounts-daemon1
libonline-accounts-qt1 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0
liboxideqtquick0 libpam-cgfs libpay2 libpkcs11-helper1
libprocess-cpp3 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1 libqmenumodel0
libqofono-qt5-0 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5contacts5 libqt5feedback5
libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5positioning5
libqt5quicktest5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5versit5
libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsane-hpaio libsystemsettings1
libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0 libthumbnailer-qt1.0
libtrust-store2 libubuntu-application-api3
libubuntu-download-manager-client1
libubuntu-download-manager-common1 libubuntu-location-service3
libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3 libubuntugestures5
libubuntumetrics5 libubuntutoolkit5 libudm-common1
libudm-priv-common1 libunity-action-qt1 libunity-api0
libunity-scopes1.0 libunity-webapps0 libunwind8
libusermetricsinput1 libusermetricsoutput1 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
libx86-1 libzmqpp4 mir-client-platform-mesa5
mir-graphics-drivers-desktop mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms10
mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x10 mir-platform-input-evdev5
network-manager-openvpn openvpn plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils
policykit-unity8 pyotherside python-cffi-backend python-configobj
python-cryptography python-debian python-defer python-enum34
python-idna python-ipaddress python-ndg-httpsclient
python-openssl python-pyasn1 python-pycurl python-pyexiv2
python-pyexiv2-doc python-requests python-urllib3
python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-apport
python3-brlapi python3-defer python3-guacamole python3-jinja2
python3-keyrings.alt python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-lazr.uri
python3-libapparmor python3-louis python3-markupsafe
python3-oauth python3-padme python3-pexpect python3-pil
python3-plainbox python3-problem-report python3-progressbar
python3-ptyprocess python3-pyparsing python3-renderpm
python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-simplejson
python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd
python3-wadllib python3-xdg python3-xlsxwriter
python3-zope.interface qmenumodel-qml qml-module-biometryd
qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qml-module-ofono
qml-module-pamauthentication0.1 qml-module-qmltermwidget1.0
qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-layouts
qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtsysteminfo qml-module-qttest
qml-module-ubuntu-components qml-module-ubuntu-components-labs
qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity qml-module-ubuntu-layouts
qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client
qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2
qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics
qml-module-ubuntu-settings-components qml-module-ubuntu-test
qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qml-module-ubuntu-web qmlscene
qtcontact5-galera qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0
qtdeclarative5-qtmir-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
qtdeclarative5-test-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtmir-desktop
qtubuntu-desktop signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-password
sqlite3 suru-icon-theme syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy
telepathy-mission-control-5 telephony-service thumbnailer-service
tone-generator ubuntu-app-launch ubuntu-app-launch-tools
ubuntu-application-api3-desktop ubuntu-application-api3-test
ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-keyboard-data ubuntu-mobile-icons
ubuntu-terminal-app ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntuone-client-data
ubuntuone-credentials-common unattended-upgrades
unity-plugin-scopes unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service
unity8-common usermetricsservice vbetool webapp-container
webbrowser-app xbrlapi xmir
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The new question "what happened exactly and how can I track it down in the future" leads a bit far away from the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Moved out the question about the terminal emulator and updated the question to better fit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `unity` package is enough for the Unity window manager, desktop compositor and basic windowing theme, it doesn't contain or depend on the whole Ubuntu desktop. To get that back you need to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Log out of your graphical user session and back in and you should be good again.

---

There may some lingering effects: the `update-alternatives` system may have selected the next best alternative after the removal of some packages. When you reinstall them they are typically restored *if their alternatives have a higher priority value*. If they have the same priority value the previous setting will remain in effect.

The console font is one such setting. Please search for questions about changing the console font.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That installed about 200 MB, and there are much less unused dependencies. The terminal still uses a weird font - it appears it's the KDE konsole... any suggestions on how to fix that too? Maybe a complete reinstallation of ubuntu on top of what i now have?

Comment: See my update. I might be able to refer you to such a question if you tell me *which* terminal you're referring to. Is it the virtual console (accessible with Ctrl+Alt+F1 through F6) or one of the graphical terminal emulators (Gnome Terminal, xterm etc.)?

Comment: Hey @David, I'm talking about the graphical terminal emulators (see up top).

Comment: Is the terminal emulator issue solved now?